# Prefix tuning in LLM uses learnable vectors to fine tune the model

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, deep-learning, natural-language-processing, transformer

I would like to implement a new architecture for Transformer.

Below description is my thought.

Prefix tuning in LLM uses learnable vectors to fine tune the model.

Is there a way to use the output generated by the Neural network as prefix?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Hi @jackson and welcome to AI Stack Exchange! If possible, please consider adding more detail to this question so that people may be able to answer it more quickly. Thanks, and we look forward to seeing you more on the site in the near future!